# MySQL Simple query took to long to return result

Tags: mysql

My simple query took too long to return result.
Here is my query:

```
select count(*) from f_logs as a 
where a.id = (
    select max(id) 
    from f_logs 
    where f_id = a.f_id 
    group by f_id
) and log_status = 'In storage';
```

This is my sample data from my table:

```
+----+-------+------------+------------+-----------------+-------------+----------------+-------------+
| id | f_id  | log_date   | log_action | log_destination | log_remarks | log_status     | log_account |
+----+-------+------------+------------+-----------------+-------------+----------------+-------------+
|  1 | 1-EC  | 2017-05-03 | Receive    | Records Unit    |             | In storage     | Records     |
|  2 | 2-EC  | 2017-05-03 | Receive    | Records Unit    |             | In storage     | Records     |
|  3 | 3-EC  | 2017-05-03 | Receive    | Records Unit    |             | In storage     | Records     |
|  4 | 4-EC  | 2017-05-03 | Receive    | Records Unit    |             | In storage     | Records     |
|  5 | 5-EC  | 2017-05-03 | Receive    | Records Unit    |             | In storage     | Records     |
|  6 | 1-EC  | 2017-05-03 | Released   | Treasury        |             | Not in Storage | Person A    |
|  7 | 7-EC  | 2017-05-03 | Receive    | Records Unit    |             | In storage     | Records     |
|  8 | 8-EC  | 2017-05-03 | Receive    | Records Unit    |             | In storage     | Records     |
|  9 | 2-EC  | 2017-05-03 | Released   | Registrar       |             | Not in Storage | Person A    |
| 10 | 10-EC | 2017-05-03 | Receive    | Records Unit    |             | In storage     | Records     |
| 11 | 11-EC | 2017-05-03 | Receive    | Records Unit    |             | In storage     | Records     |
| 12 | 12-EC | 2017-05-03 | Receive    | Records Unit    |             | In storage     | Records     |
| 13 | 3-EC  | 2017-05-03 | Released   | Registrar       |             | Not in Storage | Person B    |
| 14 | 14-EC | 2017-05-03 | Receive    | Records Unit    |             | In storage     | Records     |
| 15 | 15-EC | 2017-05-03 | Receive    | Records Unit    |             | In storage     | Records     |
| 16 | 16-EC | 2017-05-03 | Receive    | Records Unit    |             | In storage     | Records     |
| 17 | 17-EC | 2017-05-03 | Receive    | Records Unit    |             | In storage     | Records     |
| 18 | 18-EC | 2017-05-03 | Receive    | Records Unit    |             | In storage     | Records     |
| 19 | 19-EC | 2017-05-03 | Receive    | Records Unit    |             | In storage     | Records     |
| 20 | 1-EC  | 2017-05-03 | Receive    | Records Unit    |             | In storage     | Records     |
+----+-------+------------+------------+-----------------+-------------+----------------+-------------+
```

Using explain returns the following:

```
+----+--------------------+--------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table  | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+--------------------+--------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | a      | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 46439 |    10.00 | Using where                                  |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | f_logs | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 46439 |    10.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+--------------------+--------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)

Note (Code 1276): Field or reference 'gsis_new.a.f_id' of SELECT #2 was resolved in SELECT #1
Note (Code 1003): 
/* select#1 */
select count(0) AS count(*) 
from gsis_new.f_logs a 
where ((gsis_new.a.id = (

    /* select#2 */ 
    select max(gsis_new.f_logs.id) 
    from gsis_new.f_logs 
    where (gsis_new.f_logs.f_id = gsis_new.a.f_id) 
    group by gsis_new.f_logs.f_id)

) and (gsis_new.a.log_status = 'In storage'))
```

Here is what i want to happen:
I have a table named f_logs, it is used for logging of files.
I want to return the total count of records in the table.

From my sample table data. It should return '14' since 2-EC and 3-EC is marked as not in storage from row 9 and 13. 
While 1-EC is already mark as In storage again in row 20.

Note: My mySql query is working fine when the table is not populated.

Is there any chance to optimize my query?

Additional Information:
Here is the index of my f_logs table

```
+--------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name    | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| f_logs |          0 | PRIMARY     |            1 | id          | A         |       46439 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| f_logs |          1 | acountIndex |            1 | log_account | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your explain shows there might be no indices on the table.

`ALTER TABLE f_logs ADD INDEX (id), ADD INDEX (f_id);`

Comment: Now i added an index for the f_id

Comment: Thanks mate, Adding an index on the f_id did the trick for me.